# Starting tomcat hangs on boot , but run successfully in command line

Tags: ubuntu, boot, services, tomcat

I installed tomcat9 on ubuntu 16.04, which start normally on command line,

```
sudo /usr/local/tomcat9/startup.sh
```

and all projects in webapps can be loaded.

However, it always hangs on loading "webapps/docs" if i try to start it on OS boot. Here's the snapshot of catalina.out:

[image: catalina.out]

---

I've tried 3 kinds of methods to auto-start tomcat.

### 1. setup a service in diretory init.d

1) Copy file "catalina.sh" into "/etc/init.d", and rename it to "tomcat"
2) add Evirement Virables to this file:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat9
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111
```

3) use command

```
  service tomcat start
```

### 2. setup a service in systemd

1) edit file "/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service"
[image]

2) load configuration in command line

```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl start tomat
```

3) check status

```
   systemctl status tomat
```

which shows tomcat service start successfully

### 3. Setup "rc.local" service first, and add start script in "rc.local" file

1) edit file "/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.servic"

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2) edit file "/etc/rc.local "

```
  sudo /usr/local/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh
```

3) enable "rc.local" service

```
  sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

4) reboot

All these methods gave the same result: tomcat started, but loading webapps imcomplete, hanging on loading the first app "docs".

I have no idea on it, please help.

Comment: Try `Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat9"` instead of `Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat9`

Answer (score 0):

Similar behavior I once had, when on startup a different JAVA_HOME system environment variable was set.
The suspect line is this: [image: suspect line]

This looks like a different java than th one you mentioned with `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111`.

I would try something like this:

1. check your default java with `update-alternatives --config java`
2. check if somewhere a `JAVA_PATH` is set

Further you mentioned you copied `catalina.sh` to `/etc/init.d`. This could be also a problem. In our environments (actually tomcat7, but I think it is quite similar) we have a simple script in */etc/init.d* which set JAVA_HOME an start *startup.sh*. It looks something like that:

```bash
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_92/
export JAVA_HOME
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_92/jre
export JRE_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh -force
;;
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh -force
sleep 3
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
```

Perhaps you should consider to start startup.sh with your */etc/init.d* script.

I hope gave you some input to investigate your problem further.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using tomcat 8.5 and systemd.service unit, without rc.local/sysv), solution was to change with:

```
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat-foobar/
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to start the tomcat on the startup is to run it using `cron` using the `@reboot` attribute:

open up a terminal and type :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

at the end of the file enter the command:

```
@reboot PATH_TO_WHERE_TOMCAT_INSTALLED/bin/startup.sh
```

save the file and exit.

The above command will run the command once everytime computer boots up.